# Control relay with contact button on Openhab problem

Tags: openhab

Hy,

I want to control a relay with a button in openHab, and i want to create a rule to check if state is ON or OFF and after that to do a thing.

I am new in codding and i don't know what I've done wrong.

I need some help, please.

This si the code from home.items

```
    Switch buc1_releu "Bec1" (LivingRoom) { gpio="pin:18 activelow:yes initialValue:high force:true" }
    Contact buc1_intrerupator "Intrerupator [%s]" (LivingRoom) { gpio="pin:23 activelow:yes" }
```

And this si the home.rules

```
rule "buc1"
when
    Item buc1_intrerupator changed
then
       if (buc1_releu.state == ON){
        sendCommand(OFF)
    }
    else if (buc1_releu.state == OFF){
        sendCommand(ON)
    }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, this is the correct code :D

```
rule "buc1"
when
    Item buc1_intrerupator changed
then
    if (buc1_releu.state == ON) {
        buc1_releu.sendCommand(OFF)
    }
    else if (buc1_releu.state == OFF) {
        buc1_releu.sendCommand(ON)
    }
end
```